# How to send basic "Event" Measurement IOT Central (C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-central

I am struggling to get "Event" type measurements into the IOT central app.  I have successfully gotten Telemetry, State, and Location working as far as measurements go.  However, when I call SendEventAsync() from my C# app and pass in my event ("shutdown"), I never see any updates for Event in my app.

What is the proper syntax for this type of event?

Currently trying:

Code snippets:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client; 

var eventString = "shutdown"; 

await Client.SendEventAsync(new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eventString)));
```

Comment: Have you added your event to your device template? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-central/howto-connect-nodejs#event-measurements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Set up a device template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/iot-central/howto-set-up-template?WT.mc_id=article-github-dglover), the Events are the measurement type of the device stream pipeline data, so they are in the *name*=*value* format. Specifically for the *Event measurements* the format is represented as:

```
nameOfTheEvent = value
```

where, the *value* is the string type and can be used for additional info of the event, e.g. reason for shutdown, etc.

In your scenario, the following code snippet shows a message for sending a *shutdown* event to the Azure IoT Central:

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { shutdown = "User exited", })));
```

Comment: Finally!  Thank you very much, Roman, that worked  That documentation, in my opinion, is very indirect and obscure.